# Pearson correlation changes after transforming variables (time series, ARIMA) - what is wrong?

Tags: time-series, correlation, data-transformation, arima, logarithm

I have four variables (Y, X1, X2, X3). The original Y and original X1 both have positive trends and have a Pearson Correlation 0.845 (significantly positive correlation). Based on theories, the hypothesized model is Y= X1 + X2 + X3. Then I first log the four variables, and run an ARIMA (1,1,1) on the four variables, using the first difference.In the output of ARIMA (1,1,1), log Y= -.052 log X1+ ....... The relationship between Y and X1 became "negative (-.052)".

(1) Is this normal or ok? What is wrong? How to fix this? (The initial correlation between Y and X1 was positive 0.845. Now it becomes -.052.)

(2)Can I interpret that the relationship between X1 and Y is: One percent increase in X is associated with .052 percent "decrease" in Y. Is this the correct way to interpret ARIMA output?

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing wrong. You had one correlation for $(x,y)$ and a different correlation for $(f(x),g(y))$, where $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are some functions. Why should the two correlations be the same or even similar? Also, it is unclear to me what exactly the variables are in the second correlation. I understand that $g(y)=\log(y)$. But for $f(x)$, is it the fitted values from the ARIMA model, or the residuals from the ARIMA model, or yet something else?

Comment: Why would you think the correlation would be unchanged? If you want a correlation measure to be invariant to monotonic transformations, look at a Kendall or a Spearman correlation.

Comment: @RichardHardy Do you mean the resulting ARIMA's correlation -.052 (negative correlation) is ok? not a problem?

Comment: @Glen_b  Before I did anything (e.g., log transform, first difference, fit an ARIMA model), the two series both have upward trends and are positively correlated. How come the correlation becomes negative? Is this normal? Is this fine?

Comment: What is ARIMA's correlation? Could you make it specific? Regarding the change after the data transformation: plot the original series, and you will see why they are highly positively correlated. Plot the transformed series, and you will probably see why they are slightly negatively correlated. Is this fine? Well, it depends on what you want. Correlation, as long as it is correctly implemented, is neither good nor bad – it is just a technical characteristic of a pair of variables. How you use it is another matter.

Comment: @caroline What do you mean by "*ARIMA's correlation*" exactly? If you're computing the correlation of the series, why would it matter whether you fit some ARIMA model? That won't change the correlation between the series. Do you instead mean you computed correlations between residuals from an ARIMA?

Comment: @RichardHardy In the output of ARIMA (1,1,1), log Y= -.052 log X. Can I report that the relationship between X and Y is: One percent increase in X is associated with .052 percent "decrease" in Y. Is this correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Glen_b I have four variables (Y, X1, X2, X3). Y and X1 both have positive trends and have a Pearson Correlation 0.845 (significantly positive correlation). Then I run an ARIMA (1,1,1) on the four variables. I first log the four variables, then perform the first difference. In the output of ARIMA (1,1,1), log Y= -.052 log X1+ ....... The relationship between Y and X1 became "negative". Can I report that the relationship between X1 and Y is: One percent increase in X is associated with .052 percent "decrease" in Y. Is this correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RichardHardy I have four variables (Y, X1, X2, X3). Y and X1 both have positive trends and have a Pearson Correlation 0.845 (significantly positive correlation). Then I run an ARIMA (1,1,1) on the four variables. I first log the four variables, then perform the first difference. In the output of ARIMA (1,1,1), log Y= -.052 log X1+ ....... The relationship between Y and X1 became "negative". Can I report that the relationship between X1 and Y is: One percent increase in X is associated with .052 percent "decrease" in Y. Is this correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you have a relationship between Y and X1 in an ARIMA model? ARIMA models Y on itself, not on some other variable. What are you actually doing? Also please put such information in your question and use comments to briefly mention changes

Comment: @Glen_b I am running a multivariate time series model, using ARIMA (1,1,1). I got four statistics (correlations): Y and X1, Y and X2, Y and X3, Y and X4. But the relationship between Y and X1 became negative in the ARIMA output.

Comment: Multivariate ARIMA? You really need to clearly explain that *IN THE QUESTION*. Why would you leave this information out? How are we to guess? Please make the models and steps clear

Comment: @Glen_b Should I start another post? I am new to this forum. I guess everyone else knows what I am doing, except myself?

Comment: Don't post a new one. Please edit your question. There's an "edit" link under your post.

Comment: Exactly. Include all the necessary information as clearly as possible by editing the post. Try to be precise about what you did and what your problem is.

Comment: @Glen_b  I just edit the question. Would you please answer my questions? Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHardyI just edit the question. Would you please answer my questions? Thank you.

Comment: While it's okay to point out to commenters that you've edited to address their concerns, please don't directly approach people to answer your questions. We're clearly aware that you have a question and want an answer. If I become confident  that I understand the question and can readily answer it, I would do so as soon as I am able.